# Sophisticated button layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Im trying to create a large button in the center of the layout, with an image on the left,
with padding on all sides, followed by another two different textviews centered vertically

This is what im trying to achieve:
[image: This is my whole button]

Im kind of new and any help would be greatly appreciated :)

This is how I do it currently:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/requestButton"
            style="@style/request_button"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/card_icon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/requestTextView"
            style="@style/request_title_text_view"
            android:text="@string/cards_request"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bodyTextView"
            style="@style/request_body_text_view"
            android:text="@string/cards_request_card" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

And styles:

```
<style name="request_title_text_view" parent="request_body_text_view">
    <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="request_body_text_view" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">45dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">80dp</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Its just a bad practice to put those margins there hard-coded and was wondering if there is another better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
  <ConstraintLayout 
      <Button
      <ImageView
      <TextView
      <TextView
  </ConstraintLayout
 </RelativeLayout
```

Comment: Im trying to do it without constrain layout because its on a really old project and we use legacy stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/requestButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cr_icon" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/iconImageView">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/requestTextView"
                style="@style/request_title_text_view"
                android:text="@string/cr_request" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bodyTextView"
                style="@style/request_body_text_view"
                android:layout_below="@+id/requestTextView"
                android:text="@string/cr_request_body" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).